# it's been burned for two hours

Tags: present-perfect, passive-voice, present-perfect-progressive

> The farmer has been away from home for many days. This morning, his cottage suddenly began to burn. **Up to now, it's been burning for two hours.**

Can I change this boldface sentence to the following without altering its meaning?

> Up to now, it's been burned for two hours.

Comment: The construction *X has been burned for two hours* would mean *X was burned **two hours ago*** (by a single "action" that took place at that point in the past). But it's not very idiomatic, and I can't easily think of any contexts where anyone might actually *say* those words.

Comment: So do you mean "X has been burned" can't go with a period of time? Just like "I've learned to swim" can't go with a period of time?

Comment: That's right. _The cottage was burned down/destroyed by fire two days ago_ or _The cottage has been burned down. It happened two days ago>_

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5):

No, you would say "It's been burning for two hours" This is a continuous sense (indicated by the "for two hours") and so the continuous aspect is favoured.